# How can we find that all bytes receive from sockets?

Tags: c#, sockets, disconnect

I want to know when we receive all bytes from a socket without Socket.Disconnect()
method?

Yet , I use this code to receive all bytes , but i use Socket.Disconnect() method when Scoket.Send(byte[]) method is complete.

```
List<byte> LBytes = new List<byte>();
do
{
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
BytesRead = obj_socket.Receive(obj_buffer, 0);
LBytes.Append(obj_buffer);
} while (BytesRead != 0);
```

because when we disconnect the socket , socket reads 0 bytes .
for example we sent 100,000 bytes , and we should receive 100,000 bytes . How you do this?

Comment: See you're communication protocol faq for more information. Who knows what the end message bytes are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the socket is *open*, there is no way of doing this without causing it to block when it reaches the end (expecting more data).

There are several ways of doing it:

- close the socket after sending
- have some marker that means "end of message" (easy enough with encoded text - `0` being a common choice; tricky when sending arbitrary binary data, though)
- send a length prefix before the data (100,000 in this case), and *stop reading* when you get that much

If it was a `NetworkStream`, for example, using a length prefix:

```
int expecting = //TODO: read header in your chosen form
int bytesRead;
while(expecting > 0 && (bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0,
        Math.Min(expecting, buffer.Length))) > 0)
{
    // TODO: do something with the newly buffered data
    expecting -= bytesRead;
}
```